# Set new text in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jeditorpane

I am facing a problem when setting new text in `JEditorPane` in a subclass `Index` that extends `JFrame`.

```
package gui;
...
public class Index extends JFrame {
    JEditorPane editorPaneMR = new JEditorPane();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}

public Index() {
        JButton SearchButton = new JButton("OK");
        SearchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                parser GooBlog = new parser(url);
                try {
                    GooBlog.hello(); // Go to subclass parser
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this the code of subclass called parser

```
package gui;
public class parser extends Index{
    String url;

    public parser (String urlInput){
        this.url = urlInput;
    }

    public void hello () throws IOException{
        editorPaneMR.setText("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The problem is when I pressed OK button it doesn't show me the text "Hello world" in JEditorPane! and it doesn't show me any error, just nothing happened.

Comment: Check content type (or editorkit) used there. If it's e.g. html provide correct html but not plain text.

Comment: See also [*Editor Panes vs. Text Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#recap).

Comment: I don't think the pbm around the type of the editor i think it's around how the editotpaneMR field work in subclass !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code line

```
parser GooBlog = new parser(url);
```

instantiates not only a parser but also a new `Index`/`JFrame`. The `JEditorPane` of this newly created `JFrame` is used inside method `hello` and since the frame is not visible, nothing will happen.

A solution might be to provide a reference to your `JFrame` or `JEditorPane` into method `hello`, e.g.

```
public class Parser {  // does no longer extend Index
    String url;

    public Parser(String urlInput) {
        this.url = urlInput;
    }

    public void hello(JEditorPane editorPane) {  // has argument now
        editorPane.setText("Hello World");
    }
}
```

which will then be called via

```
Parser gooBlog = new Parser(url);
gooBlog.hello(Index.this.editorPaneMR);
```

*Note:* Please stick to common Java coding standards and use upper case names for classes, i.e. `Parser` instead of `parser`, and lower case variable/field/method names, e.g. `gooBlog`.